# Avoid loosing focus in children

Tags: javascript, events, onfocus, dom-events

Feel free to edit the question title if you find something better.

---

I am writing a little plugin for my website,

```js
var main = document.getElementById("main"),
  fakeInput = document.getElementById("fakeInput"),
  zone = document.getElementById("zone"),
  input = document.getElementById("input");

main.addEventListener("focusin", function() {
  zone.style.display = "block";
});
main.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
  zone.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
}
#fakeInput {
  background: blue;
  height: 22px;
}
#zone {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
click in the blue zone :<br>
<div id="main" tabindex="-1">
  <div id="fakeInput"></div>
  <div id="zone" style="display:none">
    <p>Click in the input :</p>
    <input id="input" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

when I click on it, it opens (great !). I can click (almost) anywhere, the "focusout" event is not triggered.
Almost, because the input child steal the focus to its parent.

I read here : http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html

> **focusin and focusout**
>
> Fire at the same time as focus and blur, **but bubble**

In my example, It seems that the focusin event of the input field never reach its parent.

I am looking for a way to fix this, any hints ?

Answer (score 1):

> The `focusout` event is sent to an element when it, *or any element
>   inside of it*, loses focus. This is distinct from the `blur` event in
>   that *it supports detecting the loss of focus from parent elements* (in
>   other words, it supports event bubbling).

Therefore there is a difference between this.

```
main.addEventListener("focusin", function() {
  zone.style.display = "block";
});
main.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
  zone.style.display = "none";
});
```

And this.

```
main.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  zone.style.display = "block";
});
main.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  zone.style.display = "none";
});
```

See this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bexeejqp/).

Comment: In your JSFiddle, when I click the blue zone then the input, it still lose the focus (the red zone disapear). Is it only for me ?

Answer (score 0):

> In my example, It seems that the focusin event of the input field never reach its parent.

In fact it does. Try to add some debug:

```
main.addEventListener("focusin", function(event) {
  console.log('focusin', event.target)
  zone.style.display = "block";
});
main.addEventListener("focusout", function(event) {
  console.log('focusout', event.target)
  zone.style.display = "none";
});
```

and you'll see
[image]

Comment: when I click the blue zone then the input, I only have focusin+main and focusout+main in the console

Comment: What's your browser? OS?

Comment: windows 7 and chrome up to date

Comment: Hm, it really doesn't work in windows. Anyway, FF doesn't support focusin/focusout events. If you need a crossbrowser solution, it's better to use focus/blur events. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/bbopjftp/2/